# Possibly bad merge

Tags: discussion

I've just noticed that one of my questions has been merged with another question. I've no problem with this.

However the text of the other question doesn't seem to match the question title and therefore it doesn't match my question either.

i've already got the answer I wanted so no problem but I think its a bit confusing if others see it.

My question [Install XULRunner 2.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41057/install-xulrunner-2-0)

the other is here [How do I install XULRunner since it's a requeriment for Pencil?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43517/how-do-i-install-xulrunner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the body text of the question is slightly different, the answer applies to both you and the poster. That's why it was merged.

Comment: His question appears to be something about pencil.sh which appears to be a different concept to XULRunner. The difference between asking a problem about eclipse where the solution is to reinstall java and a question about reinstalling java.  The solution may be the same but the question I believe to be quite different.

Comment: Also possibly bad form was changing the title of his question which is a query string that people may be searching for.

Comment: The question is about installing pencil, which relies on both XULRunner and it's dev tools. The question can (and now has been) updated to reflect it's title.

Comment: Much clearer thanks Marco.